# WordPress: Custom SELECT query that prints meta_values based on INPUT (JSON)

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm getting problems with a custom query of Wordpress.
I'd like to query `meta_values` from a `$_POST` and prints values that contains the input text, but right now i'm retrieving just the whole column.

That's my code:

```
    $gets = '%'.$_REQUEST['s'].'%'; // Sets meta value from input
    $meta_key = 'ricerca'; // Sets meta key

    global $wpdb;

    $metas = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = '{$meta_key}'
        AND meta_value LIKE '{$gets}'"
    );

    $response = array(); // Initialize array

    if (!empty($gets))
    {
        foreach ($metas as $meta)
        {
            $response[] = $meta->meta_value; // Set single meta as array
        }
    }

    echo json_encode( $response ); // Prints values.
    exit();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your query is correct...can show some table data and input

Comment: @HappyCoding added more infos, thanks.

Comment: try to print the query...

Comment: @HappyCoding that's the result: SELECT DISTINCT META_VALUE FROM WP_POSTMETA WHERE META_KEY = 'RICERCA' AND META_VALUE LIKE '%%'

Comment: @HappyCoding that's the image of the result, and it's not uppercase. http://imgur.com/a/f1kQb ... btw looks like $_POST is empty? God i'm getting crazy

Comment: i have updated the answer.. you can take the reference.

Answer (score 0):

That's the table screen:
[WP_POSTMETA Table IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlBKR.jpg)

That's the Input form:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

<?php if( mfn_opts_get('header-search') == 'shop' ): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
<?php endif;?>

<i class="icon_search icon-search-fine"></i>
<a href="#" class="icon_close"><i class="icon-cancel-fine"></i></a>

<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php echo $translate['search-placeholder']; ?>" />           
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="" style="display:none;" />
```

That's the result: [Search form IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PlIN.jpg)

Even if i type unknown words, it pops me up all meta_values.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the query :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = '{$meta_key}'";

if(isset($_REQUEST['s']) && !empty($_REQUEST['s']))
    $sql .= " AND meta_value LIKE '{$gets}'";

$metas = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'ricerca'  -- $_REQUEST['s'] doesn't read the input, in fact the query doesn't add "AND meta_value LIKE"..

Comment: print `$_REQUEST['s'] ` and check the value..... by the way we are using $gets variable... print that one also

Comment: That's the print: ["Stampaggio Materie Plastiche","Giardinaggio","Metallurgia Pressofusione Lavorazione Metalli","Alimentari Produzione Olio","Giardinaggio - attrezzi, prodotti e forniture","Giardinaggio - Vivai piante e fiori","Test","Abbigliamento donna","Abbigliamento - vendita al dettaglio","Web Agency, Agenzia di Comunicazione, Graphic Design",""]       It gives me all values..

Comment: Looks like, again, it doesn't read my $_POST. In fact if i print $gets or $_POST['s'] it doesn't show anything.